# Error when trying to fix database in Joomla! 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, extensions, database, migration

I wanted to fix the database because I couldn't install some modules that I needed.

So I went to **Extension Manager -> Database**, but when I clicked on Database, I got this Error appearing:

> SQL = SHOW COLUMNS IN '#__updates' WHERE field = 'infourl'

[image: Joomla Fix Database Errors]

I also need to mention that I migrated my site from Joomla! 2.5 to 3, and I got almost everything working except these few errors.

Answer (score 2):

So I've fixed this issue myself. I noticed that in my new database, the ks7hv_update_categories table was missing, and thus I couldn't open the ks7hv_updates even though it appears to be there in Phpmyadmin.
I've restored my last backup of the Joomla 2.5 version the site and I exported the ks7hv_update_categories and ks7hv_updates tables.
Opened up the exported file and copied the queries from there. 
After that, I opened the SQL tab from the database of the Joomla 3 version and first I executed: `DROP TABLE ks7hv_updates;`

Then I pasted the query that I copied before:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ks7hv_update_categories` (
  `categoryid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `parent` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `updatesite` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`categoryid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Update Categories' AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ks7hv_updates` (
  `update_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `update_site_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `extension_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `categoryid` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `element` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `type` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `folder` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
  `client_id` tinyint(3) DEFAULT '0',
  `version` varchar(10) DEFAULT '',
  `data` text NOT NULL,
  `detailsurl` text NOT NULL,
  `infourl` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`update_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Available Updates' AUTO_INCREMENT=121 ;
```

And after that I inserted the values (used the query from the same exported file) and after that it worked fine again.